# How do I make Typescript use parsers?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown

I am using Typescript with React, and I am trying to parse markdown content. There is alot of markdown-parsers out there, but none using typings in Typescript (as React components).

How do I make Typescript use parsers like [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown)?

I am trying to do things like:

```
import * as ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
// OR
import ReactMarkdown = require('react-markdown')
```

I have tried things like:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="react-markdown" />
"use strict"
declare var ReactMarkdown: any;
```

Maybe the paths is wrong. Anyway, is there a general solution for adding none-typed modules in Typescript?

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? Compilation errors? Lack of definitions?

Comment: Actually that post is a duplicate of this. But the problem is that Typescript do not find any 'react-markdown' module - because the module is not mapped in the typings file.

Comment: Error:  TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-markdown'.

Comment: I know, but that one already has an answer so it seemed more reasonable to mark this one as duplicate.

Comment: Yep. Someone edited the title, and that could be why so many clicks on the other one instead of this.